# No Method Error On Devise Sign In Attempt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

So I recently installed Devise in my Rails 3 app and now whenever I try to sign in using the Devise sign in path I get the following error:
**NoMethodError in Devise/sessions#new undefined method `line_items' for nil:NilClass**

The error is tied to the following lines: 
     **<%=@cart.line_items.sum("quantity")%>**

I’ve inherited Devise sessions controller and configureed the routing

```
 class Users::SessionsController <  Devise::SessionsController

 def new
 @cart = current_cart
 @line_item = LineItem.new
 end
 end
```

But this has no effect on the problem.  Signing on works perfectly fine whenever I remove the @cart.line_items.sum("quantity") line.

current_cart is defined as a private method in application controller:

```
   def current_cart 
   Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
   rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
   cart = Cart.create
   session[:cart_id] = cart.id
   cart
   end
```

I appreciate any help

Comment: it's stemming from your `current_cart` variable. where is this being defined?

Comment: current_cart is defined as a private method in application controller def current_cart 
      Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
      cart = Cart.create
      session[:cart_id] = cart.id
      cart
    end

Comment: Are you sure that cart = Cart.create exeucted successfully and return a real cart object? If it fails, cart will be nil and no error will be reported.

Comment: i am sure its executing successfully, Signing on works perfectly fine whenever I remove the @cart.line_items.sum("quantity") line the cart functions as expected when i add or destroy items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out - 
 i moved the  <%=@cart.line_items.sum("quantity")%> to the partial in the carts directory and that took care of it.

upon doing some more research i found that it wuld have also been resolved if i had done <% if @cart %> before the call instead. like this: